# CHROOT for shell script testing

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, chroot

I am looking at setting up a shell script in order to properly document and automate the process I am using to setup a few servers we have. In order to test the shell script through its different stages I was thinking a CHROOT would be ideal, since I can wipe out the "virtual root" and create it on the fly. I have never used CHROOT before, however.

I was just curious what are the exact steps I would need to follow to implement this process of creating a chroot (with the basic core functions that would be needed to install apache/php/etc.)? and then destroying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem is building a **working environment** under your *chroot* (all the dependencies and stuff).

I think searching online for *Linux jail creation* should help you get on track.

Tools like [**Jail Chroot Project**](http://www.jmcresearch.com/projects/jail/) or [**Jailkit**](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/) should facilitate this process.

Answer (score 1):

You may find a virtual server is better.  You can checkpoint the state, then restore it at the end of your test.  This environment would probably be a better proxy for a real server.  KVM is easy to setup and build with.